# HTML Tags showing on My account-View order page in Woocommerce

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, checkout

I have a problem showing html code in view order page:

[image: problem]

I've tried desactivating all plugins, one by one and nothing.

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce- 
Price-currencySymbol">$</span>399.990</span>
```

Any idea how can remove the html code and leave just the $ sign and the price?
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried re-installing or updating Woocommerce plugin?

Comment: Are you using any other plugin ?